# Using TipTap.dev to make a collaborative editor -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, websocket

I am using the tiptap.dev collaboration feature in my NextJS application.

When I use their built in CLI for the Hocuspocus server -> *npx @hocuspocus/cli --port 1234 --sqlite* , that example server runs on my local machine on port 1234 and everything is fine and synced between browsers and whenever I edit text in one browser, it edits it in the other which is great!

The issue started when I realized I need to actually have a server running for the frontend to listen to because the frontend will be hosted on vercel, rather than just running an example command from their docs, I found some express.js code used to set up the server.

I set the server up but nothing is happening, the frontend won't connect and I can't figure out why/what else I will need to add. I followed the documentation and literally copy/pasted what they had.

Here is the express code from the docs:
https://tiptap.dev/hocuspocus/server/examples

I am thinking maybe I am not understanding how websockets actually work.

## This is the frontend code I have:

```
import Collaboration from "@tiptap/extension-collaboration"

import StarterKit from "@tiptap/starter-kit"
import { EditorContent, useEditor } from "@tiptap/react"
import React from "react"
import { HocuspocusProvider } from "@hocuspocus/provider"
import * as Y from "yjs"

// A new Y document
const ydoc = new Y.Doc()
// Registered with a WebRTC provider
// const provider = new WebrtcProvider('example-document', ydoc)

const provider = new HocuspocusProvider({
    url: "ws://127.0.0.1:1234",
    name: "example-document",
})

const TipTapEditor = () => {

    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [
            StarterKit.configure({
                // The Collaboration extension comes with its own history handling
                history: false,
            }),
            // Register the document with Tiptap
            Collaboration.configure({
                document: provider.document,
            }),
        ],
    })

    return (
        <>
            <EditorContent
                className="w-full h-full border border-black"
                editor={editor}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default TipTapEditor
```

## And this is the express code I have

```
const express = require("express")
const expressWebsockets = require("express-ws")
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const { Server } = require("@hocuspocus/server")

// Configure Hocuspocus
const server = Server.configure({
    // ...
})

// Setup your express instance using the express-ws extension
const { app } = expressWebsockets(express())

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// A basic http route
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello World!")
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({msg: "success"})
})

// Add a websocket route for Hocuspocus
// Note: make sure to include a parameter for the document name.
// You can set any contextual data like in the onConnect hook
// and pass it to the handleConnection method.
app.ws("/collaboration/:document", (websocket, request) => {
    console.log("ws: ", websocket)
    console.log("req: ", request)
    const context = {
        user: {
            id: 1234,
            name: "Jane",
        },
    }

    server.handleConnection(websocket, request, context)
})

// Start the server
app.listen(3005, () => console.log("Listening on port 3005"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things that are off here.

1. The URL you're providing in your frontend `url: "ws://127.0.0.1:1234"` is pointing to your localhost IP still, and not the IP of a websocket server.
2. You're websocket server is listening on port `3005`, which means, even if you had the right base IP in your frontend, the port number would still mismatch.

You'll need to find the IP of your websocket server and point your frontend to it accordingly, also make sure your WSS is running, as NextJS API routes are actually serverless so that could complicate things.

Good luck!